# How to get rid of graphical glitch in virtualbox after nvidia graphics driver update

Tags: drivers, unity, nvidia, graphics, virtualbox

My computer decided to update my host graphics drivers while VirtualBox was open with Ubuntu. When it finished updating, I started getting a graphical glitch when I open the 'search your computer' menu.

[image: A Screenshot of the glitch]

What can i do to get rid of this?

> I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with unity instead of ubuntu for my X-server
>   VirtualBox Version 5.2.16 r123759 (Qt5.6.2)

Comment: Did you reboot the guest? It may also be worth to reinstall the guest additions, and to keep Virtualbox to the most recent release (5.2.16 at present).

Comment: Which graphics drivers were updated? The guest's (Ubuntu) or the host's (windows 10)?

Comment: @danzel it is the host graphics drivers

Comment: @Takkat I did restart both my host pc and my guest pc. I have now also tried reinstalling guest additions to no avail. My vbox version is: Version 5.2.16 r123759 (Qt5.6.2)

Comment: I believe this is a bug either of the host graphics driver or of the guest additions graphic driver. Ubuntu will not help you out of this, I am afraid.